# Abort subsequent mysql script execution if any one of the mysql script failed to execute

Tags: mysql, shell

I have 3 sql scripts (11.sql,12.sql & 13.sql) which contains stored procedures (or) DML statements and has to be executed one after other in ascending order. I could able to do this through bash script.

```
for sql_file in `ls *.sql`
do
    echo "Output of the $sql_file as below..."
    mysql --defaults-file=/home/sri/myfile.txt -v --safe-updates=1 << EOFMYSQL
    USE sampledb;
    SOURCE $sql_file;
EOFMYSQL
```

But whenever any one .sql file gets failed due to different reasons like below, execution has to be aborted and further .sql should not execute.

- Error Code: 1146. Table 'sampledb.table_one' doesn't exist   0.360 sec
- Access denied errors (or) Insufficient privileges

But irrespective of failure all 3 sql scripts executing one after other.I tried various options but could not able to figure out exact steps to implement this requirement of aborting sql scripts execution in case of any errors.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that, these sql scripts are being tested for MySQL database

Comment: `for sql_file in \`ls *.sql\`` - don't do that. Just use `for sql_file in *.sql`. Also, when you do need backticks, prefer `$(...)`. What's the return code from `mysql` when you getthat error message?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put your heredoc contents (i.e. lines between `EOFMYSQL`) into the appropriate *.sql files.
Then use this basic structure to execute and exit the `do` loop if mysql's exit status `$?` is not zero (because sql failed with error):

```
for sql_file in *.sql
do
  mysql --defaults-file=...  < sql_file
  [ $? -ne 0 ] && exit
done
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time and update 

But I would like to try from MySQL level instead of bash. 

I mean whenever we execute any MySQL select statement in workbench or command line we do see output messages like "x rows(s) returned" if the select statement is correct and has records.  

In the same way, if the MySQL query (DML query or stored procedure which is passing as input in .sql format) failed to execute and should stop execution further queries by showing exact output error on console when running bash script.

Answer (score 0):

I could able to check if the SQL script (Stored procedure with DML statements) is successfully executed or not by using below script. If it fails, it returns the corresponding MySQL error code/statement.

```
for sql_file in `ls *.sql`
do
mysql --defaults-file=input.txt --safe-updates=1 sampledb < $sql_file
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "$sql_file was executed"
else
echo "Aborting MySQL execution due to previous script error. Please investigate"
exit 1
fi
done
```

But I need to display below messages using bash script that explains the no of records effected for the DML statement execution. (through stored procedure scripts)

{0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings:0}

Could you please let me know how to implement this.